# Duplicate items appearing in shopping cart

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopping-cart, static-site

I'm trying to basically build a shopping cart on a static site. Items are displayed on a table. I built this shopping cart from scratch, no external jQuery shopping cart libraries used.

There's one feature I can't seem to get to work: When a user adds an item that already exists in the shopping cart, it should only increase the quantity instead of adding the item to the table.

Here's a [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mmcwxLen/) with everything I've implemented so far and a working demo, but you can also see the code below.

Here's the JS that adds the item:

```
$( "#addBtn" ).click(function() {
  var item = $("#orderMenu option:selected").text();
  var qty = $("#orderQty option:selected").text();

  var newRowContent = "<tr><td>" + qty + "</td><td>" + item + "</td>";

  $("#cart-info tbody").append(newRowContent);
});
```

Here's the simplified HTML, for the sake of simplicity:

```
<table class="table" id="cart-info">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Item</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>

<select id="orderMenu">
    <option>Foo</option>
    <option>Bar</option>
</select>

<select id="orderQty">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<button id="addBtn">ADD TO CART</button>
```

Here's the pseudocode I'd like to convert to jQuery but have no idea how.

*(Apologies for the weird pseudocode/jQuery hybrid, I'm still learning jQuery)*

```
for each <td> in #cart-info {
    if (<td>.html() == item) {
        qtyCell = the previous <td>
        oldQty = Number(qtyCell.text())
        newQty = oldQty + qty
        qtyCell.html(newQty)
        exit for loop
    }
}
```

The website itself is written purely in HTML/CSS/JS, so it is a completely static site.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ezpL78b/1/)</s>  
[new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ru5q4b6f/1/)
Use the value of each option to determine if it has already been added to the table:

```
$( "#addBtn" ).click(function() {
  var item = $("#orderMenu option:selected").text();
  var item_val = $("#orderMenu").val();
  var qty = $("#orderQty option:selected").text();

  var newRowContent = "<tr><td class='qty'>" + qty + "</td><td data-val='"+item_val+"'>" + item + "</td>";
  if ($("#cart-info tbody [data-val='"+item_val+"']").length < 1)
      $("#cart-info tbody").append(newRowContent);
    else {
        var new_qty = parseInt($("#cart-info tbody [data-val='"+item_val+"']").prev('.qty').text())+parseInt(qty);
        $("#cart-info tbody [data-val='"+item_val+"']").prev('.qty').text(new_qty);
    }
});
```

## EDIT:

fixed fiddle url

## EDIT 2

new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ru5q4b6f/1/) updating quantities

Comment: thanks Cris! However, your fiddle doesn't work with me. It doesn't add the item if it exists in the table which is great, but it doesn't increase the quantity. i.e. if there's 1 of Foo in the cart, and I add another 1 of Foo, then that row should say "2 Foo", does that make sense?

Comment: You can add an "else" block updating the quantities. I'll update the fiddle in a minute

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it on

- Maintaining a list

An array which consists of key-pair value(**JSON**) item ID and it's quantity as field
**Ex:-**

```
var items = [
      {
        itemID:101,
        name:"Mobile:"
        qty:1
      },
      {
        itemID:102,
        name:"Pen Drive"
        qty:3
      }
]
```

1. On adding a new item push the respective itemID, qty, name, etc.. into the list
2. On already exists then query with itemID and increment the qty field
   The cart you are displaying is available in `cart-info tbody` so in that case make sure you have an unique ID in row(**tr**)
   Ex: `<tr id=item-101><td>1</td><td>Mobile</td></tr>`
   Finally update the text of the respective id with your updated quantity